# easeljs mouse events on disabled stage curosr

Tags: javascript, createjs, easeljs

In my simple application i need to hide original cursor `stage.cursor = 'none'; stage.enableMouseOver()`, than i replace it with my own image

Than i register listener on `stagemousemove` event:

```
myBitmap.x = stage.mouseX;
myBitmap.y = stage.mouseY;
```

After this action  i loose access to listen mouse events on other stage objects:

```
//nothing happen on mouse over
someBitmap.on('mouseover', function() { console.log(1) });
```

Is there any possible solutions, expect check every time hitTests on my objects inside stage mouse events?

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the console? Bitmaps loaded cross domain will have issues with mouse events. Here's a [working demo](https://jsfiddle.net/fb9o8qgb/) of what you are describing.

Comment: no errors here, all images loaded from my local storage, webserver runs localy

Comment: Can you make a fiddle reproducing your issue? Or supply more code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed by setting up `cursor: none` in my css rules and removing `stage.cursor = 'none'`from js. Thanks [@Andew](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1842531/andrew) for example.